# React w/Typescript: passing <Link> as part of prop to child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to pass a prop to a child component, where the prop includes a `<Link>`. Here is the relevant code:

**Label.tsx**

```
export default function Label(props: LabelProps) {
return (
    <label className={props.addClass} htmlFor={props.label}>
        {props.title}
    </label>
    );
}
```

**Label.ts**

```
export interface LabelProps {
    label: string,
    title: string,
    addClass?: string
}
```

**Singup.tsx**

```
<Label label='acceptTerms' title={`I accept the ${<Link to='./terms'></Link>}`} />
```

The output from the following is:

I accept the [object Object]

What Typescript type do I need to use for the `title` property to render this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use type `React.ReactNode` (instead of `string`).

When passing a "complex" content:

```
<Label
  label='acceptTerms'
  title={(
    <>
      I accept the <Link to='./terms'></Link>}
    </>
  )}
/>
```